# Entropy of distribution with block matrix support

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

Let $P(X_1,X_2)$ be a discrete bivariate distribution that has the form shown in the figure below, i.e. its support can be split into blocks that do not overlap on either dimensions.

[image: Block structure of P(X_1,X_2)]

Let's build $P'(B_1,B_2)$ obtained from $P(X_1,X_2)$ by integrating (summing) the values within each block. I would like to show that the following inequality holds
$$
H(X_1) + H(X_2) - H(X_1,X_2) \ge H'(B_1) + H'(B_2) - H'(B_1,B_2)
$$
where $H$ denotes entropy values computed with respect to $P(X_1,X_2)$ and $H'$ entropy values computed using $P'(X_1,X_2)$.

**Question 1**: Any suggestion on how to prove this?

**Question 2**: How would you call a matrix like the one above? According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) the name "*block diagonal matrix*" applies only if the matrix and the blocks are squares.

Comment: I’m not sure why “block diagonal” is what you’re reaching for, since even visually this isn’t diagonal. But there’s nothing stopping you from calling this a block matrix. I’m tempted to call this a _sparse_ block matrix, but it’s ambiguous whether that sparseness applies to the individual blocks or just the block structure.

Comment: @Semiclassical: the advantage of "diagonal" is that it makes immediately clear that there can be only zeros beneath and next to each block...

Comment: But that’s not what diagonal means. Diagonal matrices are zero everywhere except on the main diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the joint distribution of $B_1, X_1, X_2$ and note that it holds
$$
\begin{align}
P(B_1, X_1, X_2) &= P(B_1|X_1,X_2) P(X_1,X_2)\\
&=P(B_1|X_1) P(X_1|X_2) P(X_2),
\end{align}
$$
which means that $B_1, X_1, X2$ form a Markov chanin $X_2 \rightarrow X_1 \rightarrow B_1$. From the data processing inequality, it holds
$$
\tag{1}
I(X_2;B_1)\leq I(X_2;X_1).
$$

Similarly, it can be shown that $B_1\rightarrow X_2 \rightarrow B_2$, which means
$$
\tag{2}
I(B_1;B_2)\leq I(B_1;X_2).
$$

From (1) and (2), it follows that 
$$
I(B_1;B_2) \leq I(X_1,;X_2).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it goes in the right direction. Obviously the solution has to do with the signal processing inequality, how could I not see that! However, there is something that does not convince me in the first equation you wrote though. Isn't that Bayes rule?

Comment: @Cesare You could view the first equation as following from Bayes rule or the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)#Example_3) for joint distributions.

Comment: But the Markov chain condition is more stringent. Otherwise every trivariate distribution would form a Markov chain. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Cesare What holds for every trivariate distribution is the first equality. It is the second equality that is more stringent and corresponds to the Markov chain property.

Comment: Oh now I see that :-)